# I want to apply python subprocess to follow three commands but I am failing to do so?

Tags: subprocess, python-3.7, virtual-environment

The three commands are :

1. Start the Virtual Environment by this command - source Detect_Outliers_In_Dataset/bin/activate
2. Change the directory by this command - cd Outlier_Detection
3. Start running Django Server by this command - python3 manage.py runserver

---

```
import subprocess
import pdb

p1 = subprocess.run("source Detect_Outliers_In_Dataset/bin/activate | cd Outlier_Detection | python3 manage.py runserver", capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)
```

---

This is the error :

ompletedProcess(args='source Detect_Outliers_In_Dataset/bin/activate | cd Outlier_Detection | python3 manage.py runserver', returncode=2, stdout='', stderr="/bin/sh: 1: source: not found\n/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to Outlier_Detection\npython3: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory\n")